# What is the prefix of L={⟨M⟩ | M is TM that accepts every palindrome over its alphabet }?

Tags: computer-science, regular-language, turing-machines, decidable

I am trying to find the prefix of L={⟨M⟩ | M  is TM that accepts every palindrome over its alphabet }, but I am not sure how to do it since it involves a Turing Machine in it. Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suited to being asked on https://cs.stackexchange.com/.